# How to set default namespace with net.sf.saxon.Query in Saxon-HE 9.6 in command line?

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon

As seen in the thread [How to parse HTML using XPath with Saxon-HE in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27820173/how-to-parse-html-using-xpath-with-saxon-he-in-command-line), I try to query HTML with Saxon and XPath.

What I tried so far from within my Linux shell :

```
java -classpath "./tagsoup-1.2.jar:./saxon9he.jar" \
    net.sf.saxon.Query \
   -x:org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser \
   -s:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826172 \
   -qs:'/*:html/*:head/*:title/text()'
```

It works, but I would like to set a **default namespace** to be able to query the HTML file without prefix or wildcard, by example :

```
/html/head/title/text()
```

should be a valid query.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XQuery you can set `declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";` so at least in theory if you start your `qs` query argument `-qs:'declare default element namespace "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";/*:html/*:head/*:title/text()'`with that you should be able to use `//body`. Whether it is possible and feasible in your shell to write and escape all those quotes I don't know, using a query file might be easier in the long run.